# Access to raw query parameters in ASP.NET Core

Tags: query-string, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to access to raw query parameters in ASP.NET Core 2.0
Currently `HttpRequest.Query` provides access to strings decoded from url encoded encoding, but it decodes it incorrectly.
How can I access to raw parameters instead of parsing full query string by hands?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I overcome this issue.

So, how I did it?

I used `QueryFeature` class from [asp.net core source](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Features/QueryFeature.cs) and replaced call to `QueryHelpers.ParseNullableQuery` ([you can find it here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/QueryHelpers.cs)) with slightly changed implementation of this helper without call to `Uri.UnescapeDataString` to parameter value.

Then created middleware class that sets my custom `QueryFeature` for `HttpContext`:

```cs
context.Features.Set<IQueryFeature>(new MyQueryFeature(context.Features));
```

and used it during app configure.

Don't forget that after this all your parameters will stay url encoded if they were.